# Docker-compose logs for yml with non-default name

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, containers, docker-logs

I have 2 docker-compose files.
One of them has a non-default docker-compose file name `docker-compose-services.yml`.
The second one is `docker-compose.yml`.

**I need to follow logs from time to time for `docker-compose-services.yml`. Is there an option to follow logs for `docker-compose-services.yml` or for a project, if I wrap the containers up into one project?**

I tried:
`docker-compose logs -f` - for containers defined in docker-compose.yml.
`docker-compose logs --file` - does not exist.
`docker ps -q | xargs -L 1 docker logs` -  logs for all running containers. That's not what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view the logs for non-default docker-compose file (`docker-compose-services.yml`), you need to specify the file name before the `logs` command.

Let's say we have a redis container in `docker-compose-services.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

We can view the logs using this command

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose-service.yaml logs -f
```

Comment: Thank you, @justin-miguel-zamora. It's exactly what i needed.